# A Logger for keyboard tappings

Tags: android

I searched a lot and couldn't find it on the internet.

I have an `EditText`, and I want to make a logger for the user tappings on the keyboard.

For example the user write "beautiful", so the logger will have:

```
15:09:12 - 'b' 
15:09:13 - 'e'
15:09:13 - 'a'
15:09:14 - 'u'
15:09:15 - 't'
15:09:15 - '(delete)'
15:09:16 - 't'
15:09:16 - 'i'
15:09:17 - 'f'
15:09:18 - 'u'
15:09:18 - 'l'
```

some record of the user keyboard taps.

In addition to that it can export record as a text file.

Please help me, it doesn't look so hard, I just don't have the knowlage to do it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
EditText  editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    editText.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.d("OnKeyListener", keyCode);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

EDIT:

onKeyListener doesn't work for soft keyboards. However, I would advice you to explore the [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) class if you want a more reliable solution.

Comment: Great man! you helped me so much.. I chose the TextWatcher class.. much more efficient for me